# PL/SQL SELECT INTO error (ORA-00905)

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I know that query(select * into A from B) is used in oracle 11g.
But error(ORA-00905 : missing keyword) was popped up.
Are there configures I have to ?

Comment: what is your full query you have executed?

Comment: Please show us your full procedure. `select ... into` is **PL/SQL**, it's not regular SQL.

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is for assigning variables, it looks like you want `CREATE TABLE .. AS SELECT ... FROM`. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae25e/1)

Comment: That query is only used in procedure?

Answer (score 4):

If `A` is a table and you want to insert all records from table `B` into `A`, you can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT *
FROM B
```

and if you want to create a table named `A` from the results of query specifically from table `A`, use `CREATE TABLE`

```
create table A as 
select * from B
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "... specifically from table B ... " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in PL/SQL:

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT...FROM B' INTO A
```

Where B is the table an A a variable

A complete example:

```
DECLARE
    IND NUMBER;
BEGIN
    ...
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT MAX(ID) FROM USER' INTO IND;
    ...

END;
```